# How to count maximum duplicate value in an array in javascript

Tags: arrays

i want to count maximum duplicate value from array and number corresponding to it.
like if i have array:-
var arr=[2,1,4,3,2,8,2,9,2];

i want to display that 4 is repeating maximum time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to find? "maximum duplicate" sounds like you are looking for the mode, which in your example would be 2.

Comment: You also want someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it e.g. with this code:

```
max = 0;
$.each(arr, function(){
    current_max = 0;
    current = this;
    $.each(arr, function(index, value){
    if(current==value){
        current_max += 1;
    }
  });
  if (current_max > max){
    max = current_max;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aec8nhvj/